# Does category Cat encode all it's properties in itself?

Tags: category-theory

I want specifically know if one can tell that the morphisms between objects in a category are functors or not without being told that the studies category is $Cat$? That means does the objects and morphisms in between them in $Cat$ contain all the information needed to recognize it's morphisms as functors, or such recognition is something external to this category?

Comment: As written this is fairly unclear, especially since one of the themes of category theory is to avoid "looking inside" objects. Towards a precisiation, I could imagine there being a notion of "category object" (in the sense of ["group object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object), etc.), and you could then ask whether every object in $Cat$ is a category object *(hopefully the answer would trivially be "yes"!)*.

Comment: @Noah That is what exactly I mean, "without looking underneath the objects", can one tell those morphisms are structure preserving and what they are preserving is the structure of a category? And of course when one is told that the category at hand is $Cat$, then you know that the objects in it are categories, but what if I give you an anonymous category. Is there any of the properties of the $Cat$ encoded in it's objects and the morphisms in between them?

Comment: My point is that I don't understand what those questions even mean really. You need to make this more precise before it can be answered. It would help for instance if you could give an example of a category which in some sense encodes information about itself, since this would clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: @Noah Got it, Thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually the answer to your precise question is no : just like there are groups that aren't group objects in the category of groups (actually group objects in groups  are precisely abelian groups), the notion of category object in the category of categories is a special one. Categories are category-objects in sets.

Comment: @alpal : your question sounds like (correct me if I'm wrong)  "can I look at an abstract category $C$ and tell whether it's the category of categories ?" - the answer to that will dpeend a lot on two things : what you mean by "look at", and what you mean by "it's the category of categories" : do you mean literally equal ? (in which case trivially no) isomorphic ? equivalent ? The most sensible thing seems to be asking for "equivalent", and "look at" needs to be made precise : what kind of properties are you allowed to investigate ?

Comment: @Max Hm, what are category-objects in $Cat$ then?

Comment: @NoahSchweber they're not that easy to describe. The definition is simple : phrase the definition of usual category in terms of sets and maps between them, and transport this to categories. So you get a category $C_0$ of objects, a category $C_1$ of arrows, maps $s,t : C_1\to C_0$, a map $1 : C_0\to C_1$ which is a section of both $s,t$, a composition map $comp : C_1\times_{C_0}C_1\to C_1$ and this satisfies a certain amount of axioms. If you require $C_0$ to be discrete (that is, a set), then you can something like a $2$-category

Comment: @NoahSchweber An internal category in $\mathbf{Cat}$ is (by definition) a [double category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category).

Comment: @Max I might be wrong, but I thought category theory, and specifically it's axioms, are sort of a language on top of which we can define or model things including mathematical structures. Let me ask my question in a different way. If I give you an arbitrary category, can you tell if the morphisms in this category represent functors? Or you need to have access to extra information, like for example being able to look inside the objects to realize that those morphisms are in fact functors, ...

Comment: ... and if that is the case then we have violated the assumption in category theory that says that we shouldn't look inside the objects. The upshot is that how can we use the language of category theory to describe a structure if we can not look inside it's objects? Please let me know where and which part have I got it wrong? Thanks

Comment: ... or maybe following will clear out further the source of my confusion. As far as I have seen in category theory literature, we start with lets say with categories and functors in between them, and then zoom out and look at all those categories as the objects of our new category and those functors as the morphisms of the new category. But then we say in category theory we can not go back the other way around! ...

Comment: ...Or maybe I am wrong and there is a way of going back, and it is through n-categories so that the functors act as 1-cells and morphisms as 2-cells and then by looking at an arbitrary 2-categories we can tell that those 1-cells are functors!!!

Comment: What does "the morphisms in this category represent functors" mean ?

Comment: @NoahSchweber An issue here is that "being a category-object" is not a structure on a single object, but on an internal *graph*, $M\rightrightarrows O$. The correspondence between e.g. "$x$ is a group object" and "homs into $x$ admit a natural group structure" gets messed up by the fact that categories aren't a singly-typed theory. (This can't be gotten around by using a singly-typed variant with a partial multiplication.) On the other hand it's true that there's a natural category structure *extending* the homs into $x$ for any category $x$-the category of categories is enriched over itself.

Answer (score 3):

The question as it is right know seems to be the following:

> Given a category $\mathcal C$, how can I know if $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal C) = \operatorname{Mor}(\mathsf{Cat})$?

Then the question does not make much sense. For example, you can probably find a bijection $\phi : \operatorname{Mor}(\mathsf{Cat}) \to \operatorname{Mor}(\mathsf{Set})$ and then craft a new category $\mathcal C$ whose objects are the small sets of and whose morphism class is $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathsf{Cat})$ by setting the sets $\mathcal C(S,T)$ to be $\phi^{-1}(\mathsf{Set}(S,T))$ for each sets $S,T$. So $\mathcal C$ is now a category whose morphism *are* functors. But what you have done is just renaming each set-function by the name of a functor. It does not tell you anything about $\mathcal C$ or its properties. (And actually, depending on your foundations, this construction might be simply wrong/ill-typed.)

A more sensible question is:

> Given a category $\mathcal C$, how can I know if $\mathcal C$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{Cat}$?

Then the question has been tackle by Lawvere under the name *Elementary Theory of the Category of Categories* (see [ETCC](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC)).